# Return rows of data from mysql but handle them as a single record, possible?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I found a simular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295783/sql-server-merging-several-rows-of-data-into-a-single-row), but is there a way in mySql in my case?

I store the data like this (in order to be able to add any kind of data i want):

```
ID   FILE PROPERTY    VALUE
---------------------------
1    1    Created     2017-08-03
2    1    Name        John Smith
3    1    Age         12
```

Would like to return it as this (to be able to sort/filter and calculate on it lika a single record) :

```
FILE CREATED     NAME        AGE
--------------------------------
1    2017-08-03  John Smith  12
```

Is it possible with PHP, PDO and MYSQL?

Comment: I think you may have issues with your data structure. You would probably be better of having a `properties` table and store that id in your main table. Further more much of MSSQL can be used in MySQL, have you tired to port it over?

Comment: Thx JonP for commenting.

My idea is to not have a main table, but only have an object ("file" in this case) be represented by a dynamic set of properties. But i still need to do regular sql work on in, like sort and group...

Comment: The thing is, joins or any other operation involving `strings` can be much more inefficient than on an `int` data type. Furher more you are storing all your values as `strings` which will make sorting by `int` or `date` inefficient as you will need to cast to the appropriate data type first

Comment: Ok, so lets say the property is represented by a number int instead, and preformance issues are not so important, could you give me a query example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question if someone else is searching for something simular.

I ended up using GROUP_CONCAT to retrieve multiple row data into a single row, from that i could handle the data as i needed.